# Why does C++ allow for the declaration of an incomplete type inside its own definition?

Tags: c++, incomplete-type, static-data

[[class.static.data]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static#data-2):

> The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class
>   definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other
>   than *cv* `void`. ...

That means, this is a valid code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S
{
   static S s;
};

S S::s;

int main()
{
    std::cout << &(S::s) << '\n';
    std::cout << &(S::S::s) << '\n';
}
```

The snippet above prints the same address for `&(S::s)` and `&(S::S::s)`.

What is the reason for allowing such a construction in C++?

Comment: Singletons come to mind. The merits of a singleton defined like that are another matter.

Comment: Because the storage for `static S s;` is not allocated inside an instance of `S` so the sizeof `S` is known at compile time.  Remove the `static` and you get error(s).

Comment: Im a bit confused. The quote is about definitions of static data members, but the question seems to be about the injected class name. This would work exactly the same with any other thing declared inside `S`.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's pretty clear to me. But my question is: what is the purpose of allowing this construction in C++? The compiler could simply emit an error in this case, as it doesn't add anything to the code, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I wanted a static S::s, how else would I declare it?

Comment: Sorry about the accidental edit. I rolled it back. I have to not try to edit before I have my first coffee. I thought I was editing the code that I copied to ideone..

Comment: @drescherjm good morning ;)

Comment: "That means, this is a valid code:" No, that means `S::s.s` is valid. (`S::S::x` is indeed valid, but that is for another reason.)

Comment: The link in the question seems to be broken